# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LabeL'

Tags: module, anaconda, spyder, modulenotfounderror

I keep getting the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LabeL'

I am using Spyder

I searched for other issues and couldn't find a solution or duplication and I already searched in Google and didn't find any good information or help. No examples involve LabeL, and there are no resources explain what LabeL is with the capital L's. I am brand new to coding/anaconda/python.

I have gone into the Anaconda and the regular command prompt and done pip install LabeL but still get this error.

I have tried updating Anaconda but got a ton of errors and do not think that is the problem.

It may have to do with the wrong python interpreter (3.9.12 but I have 3.11.4 downloaded) but I don't know how these are related.